# honored and humbled

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

I have read somewhere the phrase "honored and humbled by being invited to the party". I am at a loss why we have used the word humbled that means humiliated. Isn't it unsuitable to use the said word here that has a negative meaning?

Comment: Did you actually look up humbled in a dictionary?

Comment: "Humble" is one of a group of words which have two related but fundamentally different meanings, one to do with social status or evaluation relative to other people, and the other to do with inner evaluation of self. Other examples are "pride", "shame" and "respect". In my experience, the social meaning refers to something separating and often destructive, the inner meaning is something affirming and connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase be/feel humbled.

Your confusion about the word "humbled" is valid and intelligible as some dictionaries say that the word humbled also means humiliated, disgraced or abased. Please refer to entries 2 and 4 under transitive verb humble in The Free Dictionary. In fact, the phrase be/feel humbled is used in two main senses as follows:

- To completely or unexpectedly defeat someone who seemed better or stronger than you. For example: The world champion was humbled by an a foreign outsider.
- You feel less important or proud because of some favor, help or good opportunity offered to you irrespective of you deserve it or not. I think it's an exaggerated way of expressing your gratitude to somebody who has offered you something good
  or did you a favor.

So your sentence means  I feel that it is an honor to me that you have invited me to the party though I think I don't deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

"Humbled" does not mean "humiliated". It means "made humble" and that means "not proud or haughty."

The phrase "honored and humbled" means that the occasion is greater than the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a bit of a paradox in the phrase, and this paradox gives it a rhetorical effectiveness (which in turn has made it a cliché).

But it's not because *humbled* means *humiliated*. There are two definitions on [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/humble), for instance, that are more relevant. *Humbled* is the past participle of a verb, so here's the closest verbal definition:

> to make meek:
> *to humble one's heart.*

The trouble is that when you look up *meek*, you find definitions using *humble*... so let's check the same site's closest adjectival definition for *humble:*

> not proud or arrogant; modest:
> *Though very successful, she remained humble.*

The key is that English makes a distinction between humility and humiliation, where humility is seen as a positive trait. And it is indeed best defined as not being arrogant — excessively proud.<sup>1</sup>

So where does this come into the "honored and humbled" formula? A humble person  is one who...

- does not think they are better or more important than others
- realizes that their success comes at least partly from outside themselves
- is grateful for all the support, trust, and love they receive
- does not believe they are owed anything

Hence, a person can be "honored" — receive the honour of the award — while also reassuring the audience that their response is gratitude, not gloating.

Another example of this feeling that might be familiar: Someone gives you a difficult task or trusts you to keep a secret or asks you for help with a tender area of their life. If you're a humble person, you simultaneously feel that they're honoring you by their estimation of your abilities or your trustworthiness or your insight, and also feel a sudden tension between *your* awareness of your abilities or temptation to share secrets or lack of insight. The awareness may have been there before, but the tension is prompted by the honoring. We described that as being both honored and humbled.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>  This is shared by  a few Western European languages and probably owes something to the Judeo-Christian milieu that the languages grew up in, since the Bible is full of positive references to humility — e.g. [Matthew 11:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2011:29&version=NIV;KJV), where Jesus, believed to be God's own son, claims to be "gentle and humble" (NIV) or "meek and lowly" (KJV). Now there's a paradox for you!</sub>